# Cloudera Quickstart VM doesn't work properly in VirtualBox after updating

Tags: virtualbox

The Cloudera Quickstart VM version 5.4 is woefully out of date. When I did a `yum upgrade` it wanted to download 930 packages, totaling 2.8GB. Once I did this and reboot, the VM desktop no longer resizes properly when I resize the VirtualBox window.
[image]
What do I need to do to make resizing work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is necessary to re-install the VirtualBox Guest Additions. You do this by:

1. Devices->Insert Guest Additions CD Image.
2. sudo bash
3. sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
4. reboot